# Generic method does not return values to dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

I have some multiplied code which suppose to be easily merged under common method.

```
public void LoadApples(IEnumerable<Apple> apples)
    {
        _apples.Clear(); //_apples = List<Apple>
        _apples.AddRange(apples);
        ApplesId = _apples.ToDictionary(keySelector: m => m.Id, elementSelector: m => m); //ApplesId  = Dictionary<int, Apple>
    }
```

I have exactly same code for pears and oranges. Sounds like a good job for some generic method. So I wrote this:

```
public void LoadData<T>(IEnumerable<T> t, List<T> l, Dictionary<int, T> d) where T : IDatabaseValue 
//IDatabaseValue has fields int Id and string Name
    {
        l.Clear();
        l.AddRange(t);
        d = l.ToDictionary(keySelector: m => m.Id, elementSelector: m => m);
    }
```

List is filled fine with values from Enumerable. Dictionary is also filled with values, though **it's not transfered into original dictionary**. How to achieve that secret art of passing values from method? :/

Code to run that generic method is just

```
LoadData(apples, _apples, AppleId);
```

Both list and dictionary are declared earlier in the code.

Comment: ToDictionary creates a new dictionary so the last parameter needs to be an out or ref parameter to allow changing the reference. Using the Dictionary as return might be better. So that the call would look like `AppleId = LoadData(apples, _apples);`

Comment: Changing parameter to field would be too much work. Return looks stupid, but does it's job. Thanks.

Comment: There's a *lot* of context we don't have here. Note how in your first method, you're assigning to `ApplesId` which is presumably a property. In your second method you're assigning to a *parameter*, just before the end of the method - which is pointless unless it's an out/ref parameter. Perhaps you need to read https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html?

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly a bit more to unpack here than just the comment from @Ralf. Just to be short: this seems like a crude design, e.g.:

- why use an extra `List` when the `Dictionary` might suffice?
- why not to use `_apples = apples.ToList()` also?

But back to the question. The immediate answer is the same as Ralf suggested:

change the method to:

```
public Dictionary<int, T> LoadData<T>(IEnumerable<T> t, List<T> l) where T : IDatabaseValue 
{
    l.Clear();
    l.AddRange(t);
    return l.ToDictionary(keySelector: m => m.Id, elementSelector: m => m);
}
```

and call it with `AppleId = LoadData(apples, _apples);`

Based on the fact that this lead you to ask on SO, I'd recommend studying the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) a bit ;)

Another option would be: pass the `Dictionary` by reference

```
public void LoadData<T>(IEnumerable<T> t, List<T> l, ref Dictionary<int, T> d) where T : IDatabaseValue 
{
    l.Clear();
    l.AddRange(t);
    d = l.ToDictionary(keySelector: m => m.Id, elementSelector: m => m);
}
//------------
//with call
LoadData(apples, _apples, ref AppleId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can Do like this

```
public Dictionary<int, T> LoadData<T>(IEnumerable<T> t, List<T> l) where T : IDatabaseValue 
//IDatabaseValue has fields int Id and string Name
    {
        l.Clear();
        l.AddRange(t);
        return l.ToDictionary(keySelector: m => m.Id, elementSelector: m => m);
    }
```

Change code where your calling this method

```
ApplesId = LoadData<Apple>(apples,_apples);
```